# Printing barcode in oracle reports -attaching plls

Tags: oracle, printing, report, barcode, code39

I am using pll library to print barcode in Oracle reports. Its working fine in Local machine. It looks like Oracle Reports can't find this PLL file while running from the front end. 
My question is where to place this .pll file in the reports server?? 
How can I get this working?

Regards,
Sharon

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never...

When you attach the library in the builder make sure that you remove the path to the library, then place the library on the server and make sure it is in a directory that is included in the REPORTS_PATH.